# Using Bluetooth through a Linux Docker container running on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, bluetooth, nintendo

I'm trying to run https://github.com/mart1nro/joycontrol to spoof joycons from my PC.
I'm trying to run it in a Linux (ubuntu:18.04) Docker container running in Windows 10 but it can't seem to find the Bluetooth devices. Here's my simple Dockerfile: https://github.com/juharris/joycontrol/blob/master/Dockerfile in there you can see the `docker run` commands that I tried. I tried with `--net=host --privileged` and `--net=host --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_ADMIN`.

The error I get is: `OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol`.

Any suggestions to get Bluetooth working through a Linux container on Windows or joycon spoofing alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation. I need to use bluetooth inside a Docker container that is running inside a Windows 10 machine. Have you had any success?

Comment: @Salivan after lots of searching, I've seen many people conclude that it's not possible yet, sorry.

Comment: thanks for your response.